# Export XML to path with special characters

Tags: xml, import, export, xml-serialization, powershell-2.0

I am creating a PowerShell GUI script, that migrates the server configurations by exporting to .xml the current configurations, to then apply it to another machine.

I have found that the cmdlet `Export-Clixml` doesnt work if I select folders with special character like `][ sss ]! ' @  # $% (<`.

This problem is also in the cmdlet `Test-Path`, but I have found that the .net Method, doesnot have this bugs while testing this kind of paths `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($DestinationPath +  '\ServerConfig.xml')`

My question is ¿how to export and import an .xml with .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you a) avoid putting special characters in your paths, and b) upgrade to at least PowerShell v3, so you can use `Export-Clixml -LiteralPath` (and `Test-Path -LiteralPath`).

If for some obscure reason that isn't possible you could try

```
$xml = $data | ConvertTo-Xml
$xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')
```

However, `ConvertTo-Xml` and `Export-Clixml` don't use the same schema, so you'd have to adjust your import routine as well.

Comment: I am getting, Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."

Comment: @kimopryvt Then your path has [invalid characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) in it. Fix that.